# Json.Net Serialize an array and deserialize as a list

Tags: serialization, json.net

Here is my class

```
public class Agency
{
  private IList<AgencyCommission> _commission;

    public Agency()
    {
         _commission = new List<AgencyCommission>();
    }

    public string Name {get; set;}
    public AgencyCommission[] Commissions
    {
       get {return _commissions.ToArray();}
       private set {_commissions = value;}
    }

    public void ComissionAdd(AgencyCommission commission)
    {
        if (commission != null)
        {
            _commissions.Add(commission);
        }
    }
}
```

Serializing it and then deserializing it works perfectly, until I try to add a new commission, it blows an error saying:

```
System.NotSupportedException : Collection was of a fixed size.
at System.SZArrayHelper.Add(T value)
at Agency.ComissionAdd(AgencyCommission commission) in Agency.cs: line 62
```

How to make this works ? Custom converter ? Custom Resolver ?

Any sample code highly appreciated !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution to this:

```
public AgencyCommission[] Commissions
{
   get {return _commissions.ToArray();}
   private set {_commissions = new List<AgencyCommission>(value);}
}
```